# How to restrict user to post abusive comments in a feedback form?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, user-feedback

How can a restrict a user to post abusive comments in a feedback form using code igniter, phpmyadmin,and javascript ?

Comment: This is far too broad to reasonably answer. There are a lot of potential ways, no reliable ways, and too many places to suggest.

Comment: have you  some demo ?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a report system to allow people to report abusive comments. This way you could make the decision to ban that person or even allow users to block other users. As a suggestion, maybe have an email sent to a user after a certain amount of reports, or blocks. I don't think there is a full-proof way of blocking trolls from leaving comments in your forms. Even large fortune 500 companies are struggling with these trolls who use their media sources to unleash their rude comments. If you want to sensor specific words, however, such as profanity, there are plug-ins out there for that. Basically you need a predefined list of word to sensor and allow your code to do the rest. I hope this helps you in some way.